# Get name of item which is checked from CustomListView and Pass that item in next Intent

Tags: android, android-listview

I have created one app
In my app I created custom `ListView` , In list view I add one `CheckBox`, `ImageView` and 2 `TextView` .
Now I want to pass data in next activity which is checked.
How can I do that?
ChannelListView.java

```
public class ChannelListView extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {
    CheckBox checkMarks;
    ListView allChannels;
    ArrayAdapter<DisplayChannelListData> adapter;
    Button send, back;
    DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
    List<DisplayChannelListData> channelListData;
    ChannelListView channelListView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_view);
        channelListView = this;
        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
        allChannels = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewAllChannel);
        send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnListSend);
        back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnListBack);

        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, getListViewModel());
        allChannels.setAdapter(adapter);
        allChannels.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ChannelListView.this, ChannelList.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }

    private List<DisplayChannelListData> getListViewModel() {
        channelListData = dbHelper.displayChannelsList(channelListView);

        return channelListData;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        checkMarks = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chkAllCheckMark);
        if (!checkMarks.isChecked()) {
            checkMarks.setChecked(true);

        } else {
            checkMarks.setChecked(false);
        }

    }

}
```

ListViewAdapter.java

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DisplayChannelListData> {
    private final List<DisplayChannelListData> list;
    private final Activity context;
    boolean checkAll_flag = false;
    boolean checkItem_flag = false;

    public ListViewAdapter(Activity context, List<DisplayChannelListData> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_view, list);
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;

    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        protected TextView channelTitle, channelSubTitle;
        protected ImageView channelImage;
        protected CheckBox greenCheckMark;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.all_channel_listview_item, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.channelTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtAllChannelName);
            viewHolder.channelSubTitle = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtAllChannelDesc);
            viewHolder.channelImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgAllChannelIcon);
            viewHolder.greenCheckMark = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chkAllCheckMark);
            viewHolder.greenCheckMark
                    .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                            int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
                            list.get(getPosition).setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());

                        }
                    });

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.chkAllCheckMark, viewHolder.greenCheckMark);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.imgAllChannelIcon, viewHolder.channelImage);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.txtAllChannelName, viewHolder.channelTitle);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.txtAllChannelDesc, viewHolder.channelSubTitle);

        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        viewHolder.greenCheckMark.setTag(position);
        viewHolder.greenCheckMark.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());
        viewHolder.channelImage.setImageResource(list.get(position).getDrawable_path());
        viewHolder.channelTitle.setText(list.get(position).getChannel_name());
        viewHolder.channelSubTitle.setText(list.get(position).getChannel_desc());

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

DisplayChannelListData.java

```
public class DisplayChannelListData {
    private boolean selected;
    private int drawable_path;
    private String channel_name;
    private String channel_desc;

    public DisplayChannelListData(int path,String name,String desc){
        this.drawable_path = path;
        this.channel_name = name;
        this.channel_desc = desc;
    }

    public int getDrawable_path() {
        return drawable_path;
    }

    public void setDrawable_path(int drawable_path) {
        this.drawable_path = drawable_path;
    }

    public String getChannel_name() {
        return channel_name;
    }

    public void setChannel_name(String channel_name) {
        this.channel_name = channel_name;
    }

    public String getChannel_desc() {
        return channel_desc;
    }

    public void setChannel_desc(String channel_desc) {
        this.channel_desc = channel_desc;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }




}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintain the one ArrayList while checking, like:

```
ArrayList<DisplayChannelListData> checkedChannelList=new ArrayList<DisplayChannelListData>();

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    checkMarks = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chkAllCheckMark);
    if (!checkMarks.isChecked()) {
        checkMarks.setChecked(true);
        checkedChannelList.add(channelListData.get(position));

    } else {
        checkMarks.setChecked(false);
        checkedChannelList.remove(channelListData.get(position));
    }

}
```

And, in ur onClickListener of Button, send the list of checked channels list:

```
send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ChannelListView.this, ChannelList.class);
            intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("CHANNELSLIST", checkedChannelList);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Comment: error putParcelableArrayListExtra : The method putParcelableArrayListExtra(String, ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (String, ArrayList<DisplayChannelListData>)

Comment: You can implement Parcelable in DisplayChannelListData

Comment: Ok. and how can I get this data in next activity ? using getIntent().getExtras().getString("CHANNELSLIST"); Is this right way?

Comment: use this getIntent().getExtras().getParcelableArrayList("CHANNELSLIST");

Comment: I will get an exception in this getIntent Line... 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.Demo/com.example.Demo.ChannelList}: android.os.BadParcelableException: Parcelable protocol requires a Parcelable.Creator object called  CREATOR on class com.example.Demo.DisplayChannelListData

Comment: Hey thanks a lot . It works but I get data in next activity like this : "[com.example.Demo.DisplayChannelListData@4428b260]". what should I do?